# Setting a height on an element to match another element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which as the title explains matches two elements on the page to have the same height:

```
//get sector sub navigation height
$(function() {

sectorHeight();

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', sectorHeight);
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', sectorHeight);
}

//get profile sub navigation height
profileHeight();

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', profileHeight);
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', profileHeight);
}

});


function sectorHeight() {
    var secHeight = $('#sector-content').height();
    $('.content-sub-nav').css('height', secHeight);  
}

function profileHeight() {
    var secHeight = $('.profile-article').height();
    $('.mod-profile-search').css('height', secHeight);  
}
```

This currently gets called on two different pages using different elements. How can I edit this to only make use of a single function that gets called both on page load and on resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you can use this approach:

```
function fixHeights(){
    $('.js-same-height').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var target = $(self.data('target'));
        self.height(target.height());
    });
}
```

It should work for multiple different element on the same page. You give the dynamic element the class "js-same-height" and the attribute "data-target=".css-selector"", where ".css-selector" is a selector for the element of which you want to copy the height.

And this is how it can be used on the resize event:

```
$(window).on('resize', fixHeights);
```

or:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    fixHeights();
});
```

Comment: This seems to work, how can I use this on a page resize?

Comment: You can run this function when the screen resizes, like in the updated answer.

Comment: OK what I meant to say was it retains the highest height value when resizing the window back the other way. So if the height starts at 600px then resized to 800px when going back the other way it retains 800px. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I made an example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3c7/). It seams to work there. If it doesn't help, could you link an example of your code in action?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are matching two heights. Instead of taking this approach, you can do something like this:

```
function makeCorrectHeights() {
    var maxHeight = max($(".autoheight"));
    $(".autoheight").css('height', maxHeight);  
}
```

This can be called in any page and those ones with `.autoheight` class, will adjust to the max height.